# has_many :through / join table columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, inner-join, models, has-many-through

Having the following setup :

```
  class ParentModel
    has_many :join_tables
    has_many :profiles, -> {
      select('targets.*, join_table.role_name as role_name')
    }, through: :join_tables
  end
```

I'd expect the active_record relation to returns objects with the `role_name` key. (eg: `ParentModel.profiles`)

Is there another syntax to get columns from the join table ?

Comment: Your basic approach is correct. Are you sure that it isn't working? Rails won't display `role_name` in the default inspect/output of your objects, but the method `role_name` should indeed be present on `ParentModel.profiles.first`, for example.  With that said, if you're wanting data off of a join table, it's really more than a join table, so you could just query that association itself and preload the secondary association.

Comment: Well to be honest it was working, as you're saying. We've upgraded to ruby2.5, updated a bunch of gems, etc.. looks like a side effect but as of now this expected field is missing when querying from the parent 'ParentModel.profiles'

Comment: As a first step of troubleshooting, you should check the actual SQL output (in the development log) to see if it is even querying the extra column or not. You can also look at `ParentModal.profiles.to_sql`.

Comment: Did already, like the select has no effect (getting the standard query a has_many :through produce, without the extras expected); as you're saying, 'not even querying'; weird :/

Comment: You are not inheriting from ActiveRecord or ApplicationRecord, but I guess this is just because you didn't write the whole model in the question. The join_table is singular in the db? How is this model defined?

Comment: Nope everything is ok; as said it was working. I asked to double check if i was missing something, but it sema that eerhone agree that this should work